# Create a View with One Column Containing the Result of Another Select

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm creating a view, but I need to perform another select to populate one of  the columns of that view. Here is the query I want to use for the view:

```
SELECT JOB, REL, PHASE, AVG(TCOUNT) AS AVGCOUNT, @NUMFRAMES AS NUMFRAMES, @NUMFRAMES/AVG(TCOUNT) AS REMAIN_DAYS
FROM
(SELECT
  vwFRAME_TOTALS.JOB
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.REL
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.PHASE
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.[DAY]
  ,COUNT(vwFRAME_TOTALS.FR_ID) AS TCOUNT
FROM
  vwFRAME_TOTALS
  GROUP BY JOB,REL,PHASE,DAY)
AS COUNTS
GROUP BY JOB, REL, PHASE
```

and the @NUMFRAMES comes from another `SELECT`, like so:

```
SELECT @NUMFRAMES=count(*) FROM dbo.WFR
```

How can I do this in a single statement?

Comment: Common Table Expression could be used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT JOB, REL, PHASE, AVG(TCOUNT) AS AVGCOUNT, (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.WFR) AS NUMFRAMES, (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.WFR)/AVG(TCOUNT) AS REMAIN_DAYS
FROM
(SELECT
  vwFRAME_TOTALS.JOB
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.REL
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.PHASE
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.[DAY]
  ,COUNT(vwFRAME_TOTALS.FR_ID) AS TCOUNT
FROM
  vwFRAME_TOTALS
  GROUP BY JOB,REL,PHASE,DAY)
AS COUNTS
GROUP BY JOB, REL, PHASE
```

Comment: This ended up working. I forgot you could place a subquery within the select portion of the query.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to test since I don't have your schema, but would something like this work?

```
SELECT JOB, REL, PHASE, AVG(TCOUNT) AS AVGCOUNT, NUMFRAMES, @NUMFRAMES/AVG(TCOUNT) AS REMAIN_DAYS
FROM
(SELECT
  vwFRAME_TOTALS.JOB
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.REL
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.PHASE
  ,vwFRAME_TOTALS.[DAY]
  ,COUNT(vwFRAME_TOTALS.FR_ID) AS TCOUNT
FROM
  vwFRAME_TOTALS
  GROUP BY JOB,REL,PHASE,DAY)
AS COUNTS
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(*) as NUMFRAMES FROM dbo.WFR) AS FRAMES
ON 1=1
GROUP BY JOB, REL, PHASE
```